# Selecting a grouping that matches a certain criteria, SQL

Tags: sql

I have two relations, one is a list of the areas an instructor is able to teach (`AreasOfInstructor(InstructorNo,AreaName)`) and the other is the result of a subquery that returns a list of `AreaName`s. I want to group the `AreaOfInstructor` relation by `InstructorNo`, and then return each instructor (as represented by `InstructorNo`) that is able to teach all the areas returned by the subquery.

My attempt:

```
SELECT InstructorNo
FROM AreasofInstructor
GROUP BY InstructorNo
/**WHERE THE GROUP CONTAINS* (the list of AreaNames returned by the subquery)*/
```

I'm not sure what the actual SQL commands are that will implement the stuff between the stars on the last line. Thanks for the help!

Edit: Just to be clear, what I'm looking for is the set of instructors that are able to teach in the areas that are returned by the subquery.

Comment: Can you please list here the results set that you are looking as the output of this group query

Comment: @MiyuruRatnayake I want the set of instructors that are able to teach the areas returned by the subquery

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can join both relations, group by `InstructorNo`, and then validate that the distinct count of `AreaName`s per `InstructorNo` matches the distinct count of `AreaName`s in the `AreaNames` relation.

```sql
with AreaNames as (subquery)
select i.InstructorNo, count(distinct i.AreaName)
  from AreasofInstructor i
  join AreaNames n
    on n.AreaName = i.AreaName
 group by i.InstructorNo
 having count(distinct i.AreaName) = (select count(distinct AreaName) from AreaNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Common Table Expression are more readable than a sub-query.

Check if this is what you are looking for?

```
WITH Areas (AreaName)
AS
(
    *sub-query goes here*
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    InstructorNo
FROM  
    AreasOfInstructor AOI
INNER JOIN 
    Areas A ON AOI.AreaName = A.AreaName
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify your answer so that it uses GROUP BY? I'm trying to get more practice with that operator as I don't feel like I fully understand it yet.

Comment: In your situation DISTICT is the best solution...anyway you can use group by as below:

WITH Areas (AreaName)
AS
(
 *sub-quey goes here*
)
SELECT InstructorNo
FROM AreasOfInstructor AOI
    INNER JOIN Areas A ON AOI.AreaName = A.AreaName
GROUP BY InstructorNo